# Autocomplete combobox vs2017 - properties

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a problem with combobox. I do not have properties for him. Where can I find AutoComplete properties?
Typing also does not suggest anything to me and as I enter the whole thing, I get the error.
I'm explaining what I mean - I have a combobox with many list records.
I would like the combobox to open, for example, the first three letters.

this is my code of combobox

```
 <ComboBox
            x:Name="combolista" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="10,384,0,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Width="491" 
            Grid.Column="1"
            SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Wyszukanie_miast}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding WybraneMiasto}" 
            IsEditable="True" 
            TextSearch.TextPath="Miasto">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Miasto}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="Województwo" Margin="70,0,0,0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Wojewodztwo}" Margin="150,0,0,0"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

He works but I would like to enter all the possibilities in three letters

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow. :) Could you perhaps post some of the code so we can better understand the problem you're having? If you need some help in formatting/phrasing your question, feel free to use the wizard: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/wizard

Comment: I posted below my code. 

Why are the properties of my combobox different from the properties eg in tutorials?

Comment: Ah! I see you're using WPF. (Not the ideal answer) I do not have much experience with it, but this post seems easy to follow, and explains how to go about filtering your ComboBox's data on text enter. https://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cnagel/2011/01/autocomplete-textbox-with-wpf.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use telerik : RadAutoCompleteBox if you want, but telerik is not a free library. 
you can also take a look at https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit